# Save files on remote SSH server with sudo privileges on VS Code

Tags: ssh, visual-studio-code, remote-access, vscode-remote

I'm using VS Code to edit files on my remote SSH server. My user account has sudo privileges but I cannot save the edited files in VS Code due to no permissions.
How can I get elevated permissions for this task?

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no way to elevate the remote server i am aware of.
I am having this issue as well.
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/390